# ArcGIS Exporting (ALL) layers from Table of Contents

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.3, error-000210

I'm trying to export ALL layers from the table of contents from a map document but I get the following error:

Runtime error  Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 14, 
   in    File "c:\program files 
   (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.3\arcpy\arcpy\management.py", line 2434, in 
   CopyFeatures     raise e ExecuteError: ERROR 000210: Cannot create output 
   C:\Users\jnmiller\Desktop\Global_Map.mxd\New_Shapefile.shp Failed to execute 
   (CopyFeatures).

Python Code:

```
import os, arcpy

infolder = "‪C:\Users\jnmiller\Desktop\Global_Map.mxd"
outfolder = "C:\EnterpriseFolder\NEO"
#Get name of vector layers in the TOC
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("current")
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0]
layers = [f.name for f in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "*", df) if         
f.isFeatureLayer]


for layer in layers:
    #Join output infolder to layer name and append .shp
    outfolder = os.path.join(infolder, "{}.shp".format(layer))
    arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(layer, outfolder)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With this:

```
for layer in layers:
    #Join output infolder to layer name and append .shp
    outfolder = os.path.join(infolder, "{}.shp".format(layer))
    arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(layer, outfolder)
```

You are trying to copy the features to

> C:\Users\jnmiller\Desktop\Global_Map.mxd

Which is not a folder.

I Think this is what you want:

```
for layer in layers:
    #Join output infolder to layer name and append .shp
    arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(layer, os.path.join(outfolder,"{}.shp".format(layer)))
```

Comment: I tried that but I received the following error for the CopyFeatures_Management:                                        
Parsing error SyntaxError: invalid syntax (line 13)

Comment: Add another paranthesis )

Comment: How to export Annotation feature class in case I am using FGDB??

Comment: Dont know which tool to use. Post a new question

Answer (score 1):

I think you should change  the following sentence:
outfolder = os.path.join(infolder, "{}.shp".format(layer)

1. Are you sure infoder is really a folder ?
2. The shapefile mayby wrong.It should be like "{0}.shp".format(layer)
   I hope this can help you !